# mecab-python-windowsを使ってpysummarizationをインストールしたい

Tags: python, python3, mecab

```
(base) C:\...>pip install pysummarization
Collecting pysummarization
Using cached pysummarization-1.0.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\...\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pysummarization)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in c:\...\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pysummarization)
Collecting mecab-python3 (from pysummarization)
Using cached mecab-python3-0.7.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
'mecab-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-h1_o01fh\mecab-python3\setup.py", line 41, in <module>
    include_dirs=cmd2("mecab-config --inc-dir"),
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-h1_o01fh\mecab-python3\setup.py", line 21, in cmd2
    return cmd1(strings).split()
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-h1_o01fh\mecab-python3\setup.py", line 18, in cmd1
    return os.popen(strings).readlines()[0][:-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-h1_o01fh\mecab-python3\
```

上記のように「pysummarization」をインストールしたくて、「pip install pysummarization」と実行したのですが、エラーが発生してしまいました。

ネットなどで調べていろいろと試したのですが、思うようにいきません。

pysummarizationに必要なmecabは以下のものが入っています。

```
pip list
>>mecab-python-windows (0.996.0)
```

なお、私の環境は以下の通りです。

windows7(32bit)
python3.6.4

このエラーを回避する方法をどなたが教えていただけないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

`pysummarization`は、`mecab-python3`に依存しているので、`mecab-python3`をインストールしようとしますが`mecab-python3`はWindowsに対応していないのでエラーになってしまいます。

`mecab-python-windows`は、Windowsでもpipで簡単に`mecab-python`を入れることができるパッケージです。`mecab-python3`に`mecab-python-windows`の修正が取り込まれるのがいいのですが、すぐにはできそうでないので、`mecab-python-windows`のパッケージ名を`mecab-python3`に変更するか、`pysummarization`の依存ライブラリーの名前を`mecab-python3`から`mecab-python-windows`に変更すればインストールできるようになります。

しかし、`mecab-python-windows`をソースからコンパイルするのは面倒なところがあるので、インストーラをだますため、`mecab-python3`というダミーのパッケージを作成してインストールするのが簡単な解決方法です。

作成方法は、https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject にPython Packagingのテンプレートがあるので、それをZIPでダウンロードして、`setup.py`の以下のところで`name`を`'sampleproject'`から`'mecab-python3'`に修正します。

```
name='sampleproject',  # Required
```

修正後、zipファイルにしておくと、次のように`pip install`で簡単にインストールできます。この方法だと一度作成しておくと`pysummarization`以外でも`mecab-python`が必要な場合に使えます。

```
pip install sampleproject-master.zip
```